# Make a Class variable const after declaration (run time) (with some class method)

Tags: c++, constants, runtime

I have a template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Parameter {

    T value;
    std::string name;

    Parameter(std::string name, T value) : name(name), value(value){}
    void fix() {
        // Fix this->value (make this->value const)
    }
    void print() { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};
```

and I would like at some point after initialization to 'const-ify' the value variable

```
std::string name = "variance";
double var = 1.0;
Parameter<double> variance(name, var);
variance.print();
variance.fix();
variance.value = 2.3; // Not Allowed, throws error
```

Is it possible to do so and how?

Comment: Probably not what you want, but you can create an object wrapping the type with `fix()`. Delete all default assignment/move operators and redefine them to throw an error after fixing the value. Also for this you would need a class because otherwise you could just directly change the value

Comment: A solution for this problem is making the variable private and then using accessor methods get and set. The set function will let you set the value only once, enforcing that you can't set the value again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain the same interface, and marshalling access to `value` through accessors is something you want to avoid, then you could isolate the "fixable" feature in its own dedicated type that implicitly converts to/from `T`:

```
template<typename T>
class fixable {
  bool fixed_ = false;
  T val_;

public:
  fixable() = default;
  fixable(T v) : val_(v) {}
  fixable(const fixable&) = default;
  fixable(fixable&&) = default;
  
  operator const T&() const { 
    return val_;
  }

  fixable& operator=(const T& v) {
    if(fixed_ ) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Fixable has been fixed");
    }

    val_ = v;
    return *this;
  }

  void fix() {
    fixed_ = true;
  }
};
```

You would then replace the `T` member with a `fixable<T>` within `Parameter`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Parameter {

    fixable<T> value;
    std::string name;

    Parameter(std::string name, T value) : name(name), value(value){}
    void fix() {
      value.fix();
    }
    void print() { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};
```

The main function from your question can remain exactly as-is.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, was wondering how you would use certain data types like an Eigen::MatrixXd as a fixable parameter. For example, say i had `Parameter<Eigen::MatrixXd> Z`, where I would need to access an (Eigen::MatrixXd) method `.array()` , as in `Z.array()`. It seems that I can't do this if `Z` is now a `Fixable`?

Comment: You could do: `static_cast<const Eigen::MatrixXd&>(param.value).array();` But I will acknowledge that this is awkward at best... https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cePsWMb1n

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:
Similar to abowe answer but with boolean inside the Parameter struct

```
template<typename T>
struct Parameter {
    Parameter(std::string name, T value) : name(name), value(value), bFixed(false) {}
    void fix() {
        bFixed = true;
    }
    void print() { std::cout << value << std::endl; }

    Parameter& operator=(const T& oValue)
    {
        if (bFixed)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Error fixed value..");
        }

        value = oValue;
        return *this;
    }

    std::string name;

private:
    bool bFixed;
    T value;
};

int main()
{
    std::string name = "variance";
    double var = 1.0;
    Parameter<double> variance(name, var);
    variance.print();
    variance.fix();
    variance = 2.3; // Not Allowed, throws error
}
```

Comment: Nothing prevents someone from writing `variance.value = 2.3` though. `value` **must** be made private if this approach is to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a member variable from const to non-const. However, you can create a new object in which it is const. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct example {
    T value;

    example<T const> fix() && {
        return {value};
    }
};

int main(){
    auto x = example<int>{1};
    x.value = 4; // OK
    auto y = std::move(x).fix();
    y.value = 7; // error: assignment of read-only member
}
```

The presence of `&&` forces the use of `std::move` which makes it obvious that `x` should no longer be used.